# How to add a button to select an option on gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a website so a user can log in and access their own data (through a session) - So far when they log in and are authenticated they are redirected to the user page and can see their own data (in this case it is patients seeing their medication) - I want to provide a button that corresponds with the medicine and allows the user to select the medication so I can use this in an ordering process (if selected then insert to table) -  I am not sure how to do this.

From the database there is a patient table (all tables are all made up dummy data):

[image: Patient]

A Medicine table:

[image: medicine]

And a link table that connects a patient to their specific medicines:

[image: link]

This is the code that brings up the table showing a patients own particular medicine on the user page:

user.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentbody" runat="Server" Inherits="Pages_user" CodeFile="Pages_user.aspx.vb">

<p>
   <span class="auto-style2">Please Select Your Medication&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </span>

</p>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ></asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

user.aspx.vb :

```
Partial Class Pages_user
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Laura\Final_proj\App_Data\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT pt.PatientId, pt.ForeName, pt.Username, md.Name, md.Purpose, md.Instrcutions  " +
                                    "FROM Patient pt INNER JOIN prescription pr ON pt.PatientId = pr.PatientId  " +
                                    "INNER JOIN medicine md ON md.MedicineId = pr.MedicineId Where pt.PatientId  = @PatientId"
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdstring, conn)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Session("PatientId").ToString())
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

this is what appears when the user logs in (and ive drawn on what I want to display also):

[image]

I hope someone can help been stuck on this for a wile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to you grid, like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

By default clicking this field will cause its corresponding row to be selected. You can then add a datakey that will tell the id or name or whatever of the selected item.

Comment: Please do not add 2 separate answers. Modify the original one to include changes.

Comment: This works! A select column has been added - however the other part of the questions was how is this connected to the row - will this row acknowledge that this item from the database is selected and what is a datakey? Apologies I am a beginner. I have marked your answer and give it a vote

Comment: A datakey is like a hidden column. it is not visible but can be accessed trough the grid's datakey property, (it can be your row id field) more than one datakey can be added. what it does is store the item id or other information you don't necessarily want visible to the user that can be passed on to queries and such. a quick search would give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the grid columns and add a select command field, or you can add a button field and interpret the click event.

Comment: the button will have to be connected to the table - do I edit the table through the database to do this?

Comment: If you want the button to select a row it does no have to be connected to a table just the grid, add a select command field which will highlight the selected row when clicked. to do this, on the grid click edit columns.

Comment: Hi dwight, sorry I am a beginner to this , would you have the code or an example of how to do this?

Comment: I understand how it would be ` <columns>
          <asp:commandfield showselectbutton="true"
            headertext="Select Customer"/>`   but I am not sure of how to add this to my grid as you can see from user.aspx

Comment: Add the following to you grid, like so:

asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
   <Columns>
     <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

By default clicking this field will cause its corresponding row to be selected. You can then add a datakey that will tell the id or name or whatever of the selected item.

Comment: place this: <Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
</Columns> at some point inside your gridview tag

Comment: I hadn't made the columns for my table doing this.. it has been through a session like above... Should this make a difference?